# Grunt command error

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am new to grunt. While running the grunt command, i see this error all the time

Running "protractor:firefox" (protractor) task

Warning: EINVAL, invalid argument Used --force, continuing.or alternately, it asks me to --force option which adds nothing extra.

I googled to find the issue https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1734 where they have asked to update the protractor version. I do have the latest version.

I am using firefox 37 and even tried uninstalling it but that did not made any difference.

Anything, i am missing?

Comment: Can you add your grunt Config?

Comment: As @Matho said, please add your gruntfile. It's hard to know what your error is without it.

Comment: Hi, Attached link to the file http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=08666339890663045669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was on windows machine and using cygwin client. When i ran the same command on windows command prompt, it gave me issues w.r.t modules missing. Installing those modules locally without the global option worked for me.